# access a public function from another .aspx file

Tags: asp.net

i have 2 aspx files . I need to access a public function in b.aspx from a.aspx. How can i do that in asp.net using C#

My function from a.aspx is the following:

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
       public String user()
        {
          return l1.Text;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: `b.aspx` cannot access `l1.Text`, Could you please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to access some values and strings(such as l1.Text) in a.aspx from b.aspx because i need to use them in b.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, *don't*. Don't put common logic in aspx files - put it in other classes which both pages can access. Code in a page should only be about displaying *that page*.

Don't forget that when you're displaying `b.aspx`, there *is* no instance of page `a`, logically. You could create a new one, but if you're trying to get the value of a label which was displayed previously to a user, or something like that, this could go badly wrong.

Comment: @Sangram: He could, but he shouldn't. That would allow him to access the value which happened to be relevant the last time page `a` was displayed in that AppDomain. Almost certainly not what's required.

Answer (score 0):

@Sir Jon says,Create a new Class for Properites

```
public class UserEntity()
{
    public UserEntity(string user)
       {
         User = user;
       }
      public UserEntity()
       {
       }
    public string User { get;set;}
}
```

then use and pass it on your pages:

```
   var ent = new UserEntity();
   ent.User = li.Text
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

While that's not an everyday task, it's still possible.

You could use **cross-page posting**, and then access the properties of the first page.
The MSDN article [Cross-Page Posting in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx) describes it.